# How do I clone and append multiple elements in place with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

What is a simple way to duplicate every element in a class as a sibling?  For example, it should change this HTML:

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1> Foos </h1>
        <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1> Bars </h1> 
        <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

into:

```
<body>
    <div> 
        <h1> Foos </h1>
        <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
        <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1> Bars </h1> 
        <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
        <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.duplicate-me').after(function() {
  return $(this).clone();
});
```

Use the after method from jQuery and call the clone method in the function you are passing to it.

**References:**
http://api.jquery.com/after/

http://api.jquery.com/clone/

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/2y6cqLrq/

Answer (score 2):

There you go - `append` to the parent element after `cloning` the `duplicate-me` element.

See demo below:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.duplicate-me').each(function(){
    $(this).parent().append($(this).clone());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1> Foos </h1>
    <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1> Bars </h1> 
    <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: While this works for the example HTML, it doesn't place the clones as siblings directly next to the originals

Comment: it works here! ok so what is the real situation - I mean the real HTML?

Comment: The example wasn't comprehensive.  I tried to imply 'next to' by saying 'in place' and 'duplicate' but maybe I could've been clearer

Answer (score 2):

Use [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) to insert the duplicate element created using [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) just next to it

```js
$(function(){
  $('.duplicate-me').each(function(){
    $(this).clone().insertAfter($(this))
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1> Foos </h1>
    <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1> Bars </h1> 
    <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: FWIW, no need for the second `$()` in `$(this).clone().insertAfter($(this))`, just `$(this).clone().insertAfter(this)` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

1)Clone elements with `.duplicate-me` class.

2)Append those elements to `closest` div, which is their `parent`.

Please try this:

```
$('.duplicate-me').each(function(){
    var clone= $(this).clone();
    $(this).closest('div').append(clone);
});
```

References:

- [clone](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)
- [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$('.duplicate-me').each(function(){
     var clone= $(this).clone();
     $(this).closest('div').append(clone);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1> Foos </h1>
    <span class='duplicate-me'> foo </span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1> Bars </h1> 
    <span class='duplicate-me'> bar </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @kukkuz, Yes,you're right, I don't know why i receive downvote ? :(